# Create class category with init method

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to create a class category for UIActivityIndicatorView - I would like to set it in the screen center.

So I declared:

```
@implementation UIActivityIndicatorView(Normalize)

-(UIActivityIndicatorView *) setAtScreenCenter{
    CGRect r = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGRect wheelR = CGRectMake(r.size.width / 2 - 12, r.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24);
    self = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:wheelR];
    self.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    return self;
}
@end
```

Usage:
[activityWheel setAtScreenCenter];

However, I get a compilation error:

```
Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family
```

Comment: Your method should be static

Comment: @Scar `self` if ok, in both static and instance methods. You just should assign self in an instance method.

Comment: what do you mean by static method?

Comment: `+(UIActivityIndicatorView *) setAtScreenCenter`

Comment: I took another look at your method, it actually doesn't make sense. Take a look at **CodaFi** s answer.

Comment: I don't initiate the object anywhere. Maybe it should be a void method

Comment: @Odelya if it's void, there it defeats the purpose of assigning it at all.

Comment: @Odelya Yes it should. You should only set the frame, not more.

Comment: @CodaFi Not if she calculates something that she uses more than once. Like `wheelR`.

Comment: So what should be the right answer? using void or static?

Comment: @Odelya You should use a `non-static` method, but void. Do not set `self`, but only the properties of self. Like `self.frame`.

Comment: so the initialization has to be done out of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an init method. Therefore you should not assign to self here. Just skip that line and make the method a void method (no return value).

```
@implementation UIActivityIndicatorView(Normalize)

-(void) setAtScreenCenter{
    CGRect r = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGRect wheelR = CGRectMake(r.size.width / 2 - 12, r.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24);
    self.frame = wheelR;
    self.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

}
@end
```

Now you can call it on an existing UIActivityIndicatorView to set its position like you wanted:

```
[activityWheel setAtScreenCenter];
```

Comment: But in this case I have to init the UiActivityInidactor somewhere no? So I would rather do it inside the method

Comment: @Odelya Yes, use CodaFis answer if you want to construct a new UIActivityIndicator. In your question you wrote Usage: `[activityWheel setAtScreenCenter];`, indicating that you just wanted to set up an already existing indicator.

Comment: I just declared the UIActivityIndicator - but didn't initialized it.

Comment: @Odelya The normal way to do this is `[[UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle)style]`. Then you can send your message to your instance.

Answer (score 3):

Your `setAtScreenCenter` is an instance message.  You have to send it to an existing `UIActivityIndicatorView`.  Why would you try to create a *new* `UIActivityIndicatorView` in this method?

Try this instead:

```
self.frame = wheelR;
```

You may also be rather confused about how coordinates work.  The view's frame is relative to its superview's coordinate system.  It's not relative to the screen coordinate system.  Even if your superview is full screen, its coordinate system will be different from the screen's coordinate system in all but one orientation.  You can convert the coordinates like this:

```
CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame));
p = [self.window convertPoint:p fromWindow:nil]; // convert screen -> window
p = [self.superview convertPoint:p fromView:nil]; // convert window -> my superview
self.center = p;
```

Comment: I actually want to create also the instance inside the method. To prevent multiple lines. it's a method to set and create a UIActivityIndicatorView

Comment: You would be better off sending the message to an existing instance.  As I described, the indicator's frame (or center) is relative to its superview, so you cannot properly compute the frame or center until the indicator has been added to its superview and the view hierarchy up to the window has been laid out correctly for the current interface orientation.

Comment: In other words, you should keep this as an instance method, and you should send the message to the indicator from either its superview's `layoutSubviews` method or your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: what is self in this case? the UIActivityIndicatorView or the UIViewController?

Comment: Inside the `setAtScreenCenter` method, `self` is the indicator view (assuming you leave it as an instance method).

Comment: I see. and the method actually needs to return self?

Comment: It doesn't need to.  I'd change its return type to `void`.

Comment: I tried your solution. I replaced the method to be: -(void)setAtScreenCenter{
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame));
    p = [self.window convertPoint:p fromWindow:nil]; // convert screen -> window
    p = [self.superview convertPoint:p fromView:nil]; // convert window -> my superview
    self.center = p;
} and I call it  [activityWheel setAtScreenCenter];

Comment: Maybe I need to initialize the object somewhere, no?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is more than just pedantry, the compiler is actually saving you from yourself.  You should be declaring a new UIActivityIndicator var to return, instead of trying to assign to self. A better version of the method would look like this:

```
+(UIActivityIndicatorView *)setAtScreenCenter{
    CGRect r = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGRect wheelR = CGRectMake(r.size.width / 2 - 12, r.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24);
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:wheelR];
    indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    indicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    return indicator;
}
```

As a class method, we no longer have to deal with assigning to self, and you can always be guaranteed to satisfy the return type of the method (if this were a true initializer, it would return `id` for easier subclassing).

Comment: `self.myIndicator = [UIActivityIndicator setAtScreenCenter];`

Comment: @CodaFi You got a typo there:
`self.myIndicator = [UIActivityIndicator setAtScreenCenter];`